# Devise two step confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

a have a client with a website built on RoR by other developer, the website uses devise for user authentication and registration.

The website allows users to registrate and then send them a confirmation email, when they confirm their email, then they can login, BUT they can't see the content until they are approved to see it.

My client ask me to don't allow users to login until two things happen: They confirm their email and him(my client) approve them to see the content.

I tried this adding active_for_authentication? to the user model and returning true or false deppending if they are approved or not, but like the documentation of devise saids: the method active_for_authentication? is overriden by other modules like confirmable.

How can i perform this two validation using devise?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to add authorization control in your application.
So I advice you to use [CanCan](https://github.com/cancancommunity/cancancan) gem it's easy to set and it allows you to define access rules based on your criteria.